# Can I change the level for "Connect your charger"?

Tags: cyanogenmod, battery-life

My phone HTC Desire on **cyanogen mod 7** shuts it down if the **battery level is 18%**.

Can I change this level to something lower?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is how it works, but try to re calibrate your battery and see if the battery level notification comes at a lower level..

Comment: I have a 3.2amp hour from seidio, 15% still have more volts available than the stock crap from htc at 30%

Answer (score 2):

CM6/Magic here; my phone complains at 15%. If you're shutting down at 18, something is wrong with your battery calibration.

Use your favorite recovery to wipe the battery stats, get a full charge, and then use the phone until the battery runs out.

Your battery life will appear to be worse, but it's really that the number is more accurate.

Comment: Opinion: Also, HTC has this reputation for using really low capacity batteries, and people complain that they wear out pretty quickly. Try a new battery or an after-market one with extended life. Still will want to use the battery stats wipe though.

Comment: Could you suggest what battery I can use? I have no idea what "extended life" means. Also ... can I change 15% to some other number?

Comment: Not sure you can change 15%. The "extended life" battery is an after-market battery of a different size. You'll probably need to get a different back cover for the phone.

Comment: I did the battery wipe and full charge (mobile was turned on) then used till battery ran out and now the phone shuts down at 20% ... :-( The battery is one year old.

Comment: That's...amazing. I'm out of ideas, beyond doing the same thing but not wiping this time.

Comment: Now I did what you suggest but as I read somewhere else I did the full charge while the phone was off and it looks OK now. I mean it turns off at 15%.... So back to the original question :-) 15% is very far too early.